# Determining whether any of two candidates can be an inner product on $C^1[a,b]$

Tags: inner-products

I want to determine whether any of the two inner products

$\langle f, g \rangle=\int_{b}^{a}f'(x)g'(x)dx$ (1)  and $\langle f, g \rangle=\int_{b}^{a}f'(x)g'(x)dx+f(a)g(a)$ (2)

can be inner products on $C^1[a,b]$, but am uncertain how to proceed.

$\langle f, g \rangle$ $\in$ $\left \{ \left. C^1([a,b])=f:[a,b] \to \mathbb{R} \vert f,f' {cont.}   \right \} \right.$ and the elementary identities for the inner product must hold. Can I perhaps find a simple counter example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first one is not an inner product, the second one is. You should be able to verify linearity and symmetry by yourself. The only question is whether $\langle f , f \rangle=0$ implies $f=0$. In the first case we only get $\int f'(x)^{2}dx=0$ which means $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$ and $f$ is a constant. So we cannot conclude that $f=0$. In the second case we get  $\int f'(x)^{2}dx=0$ and $f (a)=0$. Thus $f$ is again a constant and $f(a)=0$ so $f \equiv 0$.

Comment: @Ingix Thanks. Just carelessness!